# PHP OOP - Wrong object returned

Tags: php, oop, class, object

with the follow code:

```
<?php
class Loader {
    private static $instances;

    function __construct($class = null) {
        return self::instance($class);
    }

    public static function instance($class) {
        if(!isset(self::$instances[$class])) {
            self::$instances[$class] = new $class();
        }

        return self::$instances[$class];
    }
}

class Core {
}

$core = new Loader('Core');
print_r($core);

?>
```

my print_r() return the object Loader instead the object Core, which is instantiated after Loader is constructed.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hm ?

If you do

```
$core = new Loader('Core');
```

Then $core is going to be an instance of Loader...
PS : constructors don't return a value.

You don't need to instantiate Loader at all.

Do this :

```
<?php
class Loader {
    private static $instances;

    public static function instance($class) {
        if(!isset(self::$instances[$class])) {
            self::$instances[$class] = new $class();
        }

        return self::$instances[$class];
    }
}

class Core {
}

$core = Loader::instance('Core');
print_r($core);
```

Or you could do a much simpler :

```
<?php
function Load($class)
{
    static $instances;
    if(!isset($instances[$class]))
         $instances[$class] = new $class();
    return $instances[$class];
}

class Core {
}

$core = Load('Core');
print_r($core);
```

Comment: There's a mistake in the function example: you call it `Loader`, but later call it as `Load`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I could not set static variables within functions.